# Sitecore Zip File Media Item Auto Downloads in Content Editor

Tags: media-library

I have a Sitecore media item in my media library that contains a zip file. In the content editor, when I navigate to this item, it starts the download of the zip media asset. Also, the usual zip icon that appears in the Media field isn't displaying. Does anyone have any idea how this happens or what the fix is? I've checked all the configs and they are vanilla. Also, I'm on Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 180406).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you have 2 ZIP media file type item templates in Sitecore:

`/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Zip`

`/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Zip`

2. Check your Sitecore/Web config registers and associates ZIP files with this template:

```
<mediaType name="Zip file" extensions="zip">
    <mimeType>application/x-zip-compressed</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/zip</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/zip</versionedTemplate>
    <metaDataFormatter type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ZipMetaDataFormatter"/>
    <prototypes>
        <media type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.ZipMedia, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    </prototypes>
</mediaType>
```

3. Check the MIME-Types config `mimetypes.config` to prevent any conflicts for ZIP-files