# If I add a CSV file to the media library and visit that item in Sitecore, a file is downloaded automatically with the content of that media item

Tags: content-editor, media-library, content-management, iis

I want to upload a CSV file into our media library.  In our Dev environment, this works as expected, the file uploads, shows up in the content tree, mime-type/extension is getting set appropriately, and I can attach/detach/download the file.

In our QA and Production environments, if I upload a CSV file, it gets added to the content tree and mime-type/extension is set appropriately.  However, when whenever I select that item, the content editor kicks off a download automatically of that file and names it *[SitecoreItemID].ashx*.

I am thinking an IIS setting is different between the environments.  Or maybe an old sitecore setting set long ago.  Does anyone know what would cause this to occur?

UPDATE: I am only seeing this problem in IIS 7.5. Our DEV is running IIS 8.5 and it doesn't happen there.

Comment: Looks like it's a similar problem to https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16716/sitecore-zip-file-media-item-auto-downloads-in-content-editor

Comment: What is interesting is without any custom config changes, IIS 8.5 and later do not do this.  Only the servers that are running IIS 7.5 are doing this.

Answer (score -2):

according to the Sitecore documentation, the csv file is not supported.

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/42/content-hub/asset-types.html